# Composition of rotation and reflexion of two symmetries of a regular $n$-gon.

Tags: group-theory, symmetry, dihedral-groups

I know that composition of a rotation and reflexion of a regular $n-$gon in plane is reflexion and can be proved by using rotation and reflexion matrices . But I want to prove it by the fixed point method i.e.  as non-trivial rotation has one fixed point that is center of $n$-gon, whereas reflexion has infinite many fixed points which are points of the line of reflexion. Now I am unable to prove that composition of reflexion $S$ and rotation $R$ has infinite many  fixed points to become reflexion. Please suggest . Thank you .

Comment: It seems you're asking "Why does $SR$ have a line of fixed points?" A natural approach is to find/construct two fixed points, then to show the line joining these points is fixed. Without knowing the details of your set-up (e.g., your definitions of rotation and reflexion, whether you're working in Euclidean geometry, coordinate geometry, etc.) it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang it’s in plane ...

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang sir if possible please give more details